# How to implement multi view Listview that contains Gridviews in android

Tags: android, performance, android-listview, android-gridview

I want to implement the following UI with a good performance.

[image]

The UI contains grid view inside multi view listview, I have already implement it, but it is too slow, can any one advice on how to implement it with a good performance

Thanks

Comment: Do your GridViews scroll?

Comment: Why not a more performing GridLayout? More performing because you would only have **1** scrollable View, instead of **2 nested** ones.

Comment: @MikeM. The gridview is contains only two items, so the top part contains two gridviews.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I didn't use GridLayout before, do you have any tutorial or example that can help me doing this.

Comment: Get rid of the GridViews. There's no point in using a GridView unless it's scrolling. They have big overhead. If each row just has two elements, you could replace the GridViews with simple horizontal LinearLayouts.

Comment: This should be a great start: http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html

Comment: check this out. It might solve your problem : http://osdir.com/ml/Android-Developers/2013-05/msg00169.html

Comment: @MikeM. will give it a try.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Thank you very much, will check the post and try to use it.